# How to Show Color Swatches with most Recent View Products in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to show `color swatches` with the `most recent products` in magento2
in my home page, most recent products are showing now **I want to show color swatches with it**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add This Code :-

```
<?php if($_item->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE){

 $swatchBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable")->setTemplate("Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml");
   echo $swatchBlock->setProduct($_item)->toHtml();                           
} ?>
```

And Define Css In Your XML File :-

```
<head>
    <css src="Magento_Swatches::css/swatches.css"/>
</head>
```

Comment: thankuyou its working